# sIFR3 h1 height

Tags: javascript, flash, sifr

I use sifr3 for my text.
Now my problem is that i can't get the line height right for my  tag.

Can somebody please help me?
line-height, height, leading etc wont work.
Here you can find the output: 
http://www.bbp.nl/luuk-test/emmc/

ccs code:

```
.sIFR-active h1 {
  visibility: hidden;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 14pt;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: right;
  color: #ff5400;
}
```

js code:

```
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
    selector: 'h1'
    ,css: [
      '.sIFR-root { text-align: right; leading: -14;  }'
      ,'a { text-decoration: none; }'
      ,'a:link { color: #000000; }'
      ,'a:hover { color: #ff5400;; }'
    ]
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the fix myself. Not to neat, but it works:
set a height on the h1, overflow:hidden and it works